# jQuery form processing, how can I reassign a function on callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

```
 $(function(){

$(".mailbutton").click(function() {
  var email = $(".mailingfield").val();
  $.post("/PHP_scripts/mailinglist.php", { email: email }, function(data) {
        var content = $(data).find("#mailinglistform");
        $("#box").empty().append(content);
  });
 });
});
```

I'm using this to process an email address. If it fails in the PHP script the form is sent back in the '.mailinglistform' with a fresh form and some text explaining the error. The problem I have is that even though the button has the '.mailbutton' class in the callback form, the button doesn't do anything on click.

Is this because the jQuery only recognises it first time round? If so, is there a way to "reload" the 'mailbutton' .click function on callback?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that because you're only re-rendering a portion of the page, the previous jQuery you wrote does not register with the "new" mailbutton class that you've re-rendered.  To get around this, you should use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), e.g.:

```
$(".wrapper").on('click', '.mailbutton', function() {
  var email = $(".mailingfield").val();
  $.post("/PHP_scripts/mailinglist.php", { email: email }, function(data) {
        var content = $(data).find("#mailinglistform");
        $("#box").empty().append(content);
  });
 });
```

In this case, wrapper needs to be a class element that's outside of the re-rendered section (e.g. the 'content' class, maybe a class around your form, etc) of the page, and one that is constantly present (i.e. not re-rendered in the ajax call).  This will attach an onclick handler to any .mailbutton classes that are children of the wrapper class, whether they are present when the page is rendered, or if they are added to the DOM later.

Comment: $(".wrapper").on('click', '.mailingfield', function()
did you mean
$(".wrapper").on('click', '.mailbutton', function()
where mailbutton is the class element i want to add the click function to.

Comment: yes, sorry - fixed that.  That's the delegated event . . . i.e. all clicks on mailbutton classes that are children of the wrapper class will trigger the function.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind click event. When control is render again in the callback function its events are removed. Using on instead of click could rebind the events automatically.

```
 $(function(){

    $(".mailbutton").on("click", function() {
    var email = $(".mailingfield").val();
    $.post("/PHP_scripts/mailinglist.php", { email: email }, function(data) {
        var content = $(data).find("#mailinglistform");
        $("#box").empty().append(content);         
    });
    });
});
```

Comment: That appears to have had no effect,

Comment: are you expecting click of this button #mailinglistform ?

Comment: That particular usage of on() will fail, as according to the doc 
"Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on(). "  For more details, refer to the Direct and delegated events - in @joe coleman's case, he needs to use delegated events.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use AJAX with JQuery. OR you can alos user `load()`.

```
$(".mailbutton").click(function() {
        $.ajax({                                      
              url: 'api.php', // Put your calling page path here
              data: "",
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data)
              {
                //do whatever you want to do on success
              } 
        });
    });
```